# Unusable function arguments

Tags: python, function, lambda, functional-programming

Is there a syntax for user-inaccessible arguments in Python functions. Or is that even possible?

For example, I would like to define a function that takes *only* a single argument from the user but there is a need for another argument where the function needs to call itself in a different setting, such as:

```
def function(userEntry, key1 = 0):
    if key1 == 0: #setting 1 
        ##SOME INITIAL OPERATIONS ##
        key1 += 1
        function(userEntry, key1)
    if key1 == 1: #setting 2
        ##FINAL OPERATIONS##
        print('Some function of ' userEntry)
```

If done as above, user can still access key1 and initialize the program as they wish, however, I do not want user to be able to do this. I want the user to enter userEntry only while the function requires to call itself depending on the conditions on user-input and key1, operations will change.

Comment: Define an inner function ?

Comment: you can use a helper function

Comment: Defining inner function could probably work but I was hoping for a simple syntax answer to define the unusable argument.

Comment: How would that syntax work?  How would the function know if a "user" called it, or another function called it?

Comment: There is no such syntax in Python when defining the formal parameters of a function if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Offering another function to client code with the wanted signature is the straightforward solution. There are no private members in Python code, You can still consider puting those functions in a module and name the internal ones with an underscore prefix. But that is just a convention client code *should* respect.

Comment: @progmatico Thanks. I was thinking maybe there was something such as "self." variables in initializing classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that having a separate function that the user calls would be a good idea. I have made some code that works for that here:

```
key = 0

def userFunc(input):
    # Do stuff
    function(input, key)

def function(userEntry, key1 = 0):
    if key1 == 0: #setting 1 
        ##SOME INITIAL OPERATIONS ##
        print('initial operation')
        print key1
        key1 += 1
        return ##to make the function not instantly repeat itself
    if key1 == 1: #setting 2
        ##FINAL OPERATIONS##
        print('final operation')
        print key1

userFunc('inValue')
```

This would do the initial operations the first time userFunc() is called, then the final operations the next time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Have a function that the end user calls, that does what it needs to, before calling the actual function which you use everywhere else.

```
def userFunc(input):
    # Do stuff
    function(input, key)

def function
    # Does common functionality
```

Answer (score 0):

By your latest comment it looks that perhaps you want something like this:

```
class OffsetedIncrementer:
    _offset = 100

    def __init__(self, offset=100):
        OffsetedIncrementer._offset = offset

    def inc(self, x):
        return x + 1 + OffsetedIncrementer._offset


oi = OffsetedIncrementer(200)
func = oi.inc

print(func(2))
```

Output:

```
203
```

Comment: Thanks, I did end up implementing two functions inside one another. But this way seems clean as well. Though, as a novice in Python, I try and avoid Global variables within classes as much as I can.

Comment: @Semzem, avoiding shared state is not for novices, is actually a good practice. But sometimes shared state makes sense, when you really need to share something between all instances of a class. If not, and there is some configuration to pass specific to each instance, just pass it to the `__init__` and individually assign in each instance with `self._offset = offset`